# Can't access my android sqlite DB from windows

Tags: android, windows, sqlite

I have been using an SQLite database in the application I am developing for the android platform. I would like to explore the data from my PC and see the tables and entities. I don't think I have the proper security to access it when I try from the DDMS file explorer on eclipse. I can't open the data folder and when I copy it on my desktop it is empty. Does anyone know how to dump my mobile android SQLite database onto my PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use cellObject sqlite browser to browse directly from DDMS below is a link to the eclipse plugin: http://www.cellobject.net/Tools/CellObjectSQLiteXMLBrowser.aspx

Comment: Thanks I ve tried with cellObject but the thing is that it only works with the emulator and that my sqlite database with all the data is on my cellphone :s ...

Comment: Any idea why I get a config error every time I try to go to any page at cellobject.net? I have been trying to get this but I cant access their website. Does anyone have it available to dl from a different site?

Comment: I found a different place to get this plugin. If you have problems going to cellobject's website you can alternatively download it here http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/com.questoid.htm

Answer (score 0):

Without rooting your phone you can get a copy of the DB by running the app on the emulator and then use the DDMS to pull it.from there.  It will be the same as if you pulled it off your phone.

Answer (score 0):

You can get DB file your application. Even if your device not rooted.

You must add debug action: copy from \databases\database.db to sdcard. Get database path by [getDatabasePath](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath%28java.lang.String%29).
From sdcard you can get file by adb pull or File Explorer.

Also you can process back operation: copy from sdcard to app. Of couse you app at device don't 
 be started.
Иut I have not had any problems, even when the application is running, but there is no access to the base.